# Finding differences and combining multiple tree structures

Tags: c#, tree, treeview

I am in need of a function that will combine two file structures.

I have a child class, "Element" that has properties ID and Children, with ID being a string and Children being a collection of Element.

```
public class Element
{
  string ID { get; }
  IEnumerable<Element> Children { get; }
}
```

Now, I have the following structures of Elements:

```
Structure A                Structure B
  - Category 1              - Category 1
      - Child X                - Child X
      - Child Y                - Child Z
  - Category 2              - Category 3
                               - Child P
```

The difficulty lies in that some of the elements of B have been intentionally removed, so I do not want to copy those over from A. I only know the initial states of A and B.

For example, The initial difference is that B is missing "Category1|Y" and "Category2". Let's say that "X" is removed from Category B. So the The output should be:

```
Structure Output               
    - Category 1              
        - Child Y               
        - Child Z             
    - Category 2 
    - Category 3
        - Child P
```

As such, there are three steps:

1) Find the difference between A and the initial B and hold this somewhere as the "orphaned elements".

2) <-- B is altered -->

3) Add the orphaned elements back to the final structure.

Is this the right idea? Are there any easier ways to undertake this?

Comment: Linq would be useful for this. What code do you have so far?

Comment: You could also calculate the difference(D) of B(inital) to B(altered). and then combine A(initial) with B(initial) and apply D on the result. Generally this reminds me much of merging files with version control systems, so reading up on 2 and 3 way merges might help you solving this elegantly